# passing exception to controller without try/catch

Tags: php, symfony, exception, symfony4

I have made my custom Exception defined in  `$this->exception($response['error']);` .

So in my service method:

```
$response = $this->request('POST', $endpoint, $options);
    if (array_key_exists('error', $response)) {
        $this->exception($response['error']);
    }
```

Which is returning error message if key error exists in response.

And in my controler:

```
$response = $this->serviceMethod();

if (!empty($response)) {
    return $this->apiError(['error' => 'VIOLATION']);
}
```

If service method pass, response will return empty array which is fine.

Problem occurs that if service method catches error in `if()` statement and I am dumping  controller method response it never gets to that part. It finishes with that custom exception.

How can I accomplish to pass response in both ways so I can handle in in my `apiError()` method which is made to write error from response.

It's like:

```
 protected function apiError(array $errors = [], $message = ''): void
{
    throw new ApiException($errors, $message)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have a misconception there. If you want the outcome be the same in both cases (exception thrown or not) why throw an exception anyway instead of just logging an error somewhere?
Usually you want to create a different response if something goes wrong - otherwise you could also try/catch the exception in your service method already.

Comment: Okay, what are you suggesting? @Atan

Comment: Depends how sensitive the error is. If the error message is sensitive and should not be sent to the user catch the exception on an upper level (e.g. your service), log the message away and throw a new exception with a "user friendly" message. You can catch that exception in your controller and include it in your response.
`throw` is meant to be `catch`ed somewhere. You can also bubble up the exception to your controller and catch it there.

Comment: Can you share more details? `if` will not catch any exception, so if `$this->exception($response['error'])` throws any exception, you shoud catch it